# what is the problem ?: application.connect() error

Tags: python, automation, artificial-intelligence

I am a beginner developer who started to study automation by using pywinauto.

An overflow error occurs when using application.connect () to connect to an already open program.

But application.start() works fine....

Please help me if someone know this part.

The source code and error contents are as follows.

**Source code**:

```
import pywinauto

app = pywinauto.application.Application()

app.connect(title_re='Calculator')
```

**Error**:

```
OverflowError Traceback (most recent call last)
in 

 1 import pywinauto

 2 app = pywinauto.application.Application()
 ----> 3 app.connect(title_re='Calculator')

d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py in connect(self, **kwargs)

 972 ).process_id

 973 else:

 --> 974 self.process = findwindows.find_element(**kwargs).process_id
 975 connected = True

 976

d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py in find_element(**kwargs)

 82 so please see :py:func:find_elements for the full parameters description.

 83 """
 ---> 84 elements = find_elements(**kwargs)

 85

 86 if not elements:

d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py in find_elements(class_name, class_name_re, parent, process, title, title_re, top_level_only, visible_only, enabled_only, best_match, handle, ctrl_index, found_index, predicate_func, active_only, control_id, control_type, auto_id, framework_id, backend, depth)

 279 return title_regex.match(t)

 280 return False

 --> 281 elements = [elem for elem in elements if _title_match(elem)]

 282

 283 if visible_only:

d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py in (.0)

 279 return title_regex.match(t)

 280 return False

 --> 281 elements = [elem for elem in elements if _title_match(elem)]

 282

 283 if visible_only:

d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py in _title_match(w)

 275 def _title_match(w):

 276 """Match a window title to the regexp"""

 --> 277 t = w.rich_text

 278 if t is not None:

 279 return title_regex.match(t)

d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\win32_element_info.py in rich_text(self)

 81 def rich_text(self):

 82 """Return the text of the window"""

 ---> 83 return handleprops.text(self.handle)

 84

 85 name = rich_text

d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\handleprops.py in text(handle)

 86 length += 1

 87

 ---> 88 buffer_ = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length)

 89

 90 ret = win32functions.SendMessage(

d:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes_init_.py in create_unicode_buffer(init, size)

 286 return buf

 287 elif isinstance(init, int):

 --> 288 buftype = c_wchar * init

 289 buf = buftype()

 290 return buf

OverflowError: cannot fit 'int' into an index-sized integer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pywinauto
app = pywinauto.Application(backend='uia').start('calc.exe')
```

try this if you are having problem you have to say the backennd is a uia it working fine for me.

Comment: This should be problem with another application on his desktop. It can be handled on pywinauto side, but I couldn't reproduce it on my side. The issue is tracked here: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/705